# hadoop replication factor confusion

Tags: hadoop

We have 3 settings for hadoop replication namely:

```
dfs.replication.max = 10
dfs.replication.min = 1
dfs.replication     = 2
```

So dfs.replication is default replication of files in hadoop cluster until a hadoop client is setting it manually using "**setrep**".
and a hadoop client can set max replication up to **dfs.replication.mx**.

dfs.relication.min is used in two cases:

1. During safe mode, it checks whether replication of blocks is upto **dfs.replication.min** or not.
2. **dfs.replication.min** are processed synchronously. and remaining dfs.replication-dfs.replication.min are processed asynchronously.

So we have to set these configuration on each node (namenode+datanode) or only on client node?

What if setting for above three settings vary on different datanodes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replication factor can’t be set for any specific node in cluster, you can set it for entire cluster/directory/file. `dfs.replication` can be updated in running cluster in hdfs-sie.xml.

Set the replication factor for a file- `hadoop dfs -setrep -w <rep-number> file-path`

Or set it recursively for directory or for entire cluster- `hadoop fs -setrep -R -w 1 /`

Use of min and max rep factor-

1. While writing the data to datanode it is possible that many datanodes may fail. If the `dfs.namenode.replication.min` replicas written then the write operation succeed. Post to write operation the blocks replicated asynchronously until it reaches to `dfs.replication` level.
2. The max replication factor `dfs.replication.max` is used to set the replication limit of blocks. A user can’t set the blocks replication more than the limit while creating the file.
3. You can set the high replication factor for blocks of popular file to distribute the read load on the cluster.

Comment: So do i have to set configuration parameters on (namenode+datanode) or only on namenode or on all datanodes? We are using hive for data loading activites, so how can we set high replication factor for blocks of popular file to distribute the read load on the cluster.?

Comment: default blocks' replication configuration you can update in hdfs-site.xml, that is one time cluster level configuration. 
if you have to update the replication for hive table then find the table location in HDFS(default /user/hive/warehouse..) and change the replication by command- hadoop fs -setrep -R -w rep-num /user/hive/warehouse/xyz_table

Comment: do we have some configuration parameter for hive, which can make replication for that table configurable? e.g hive -e "some query" -hiveconf some.configuration.parameter

Comment: i haven't come across any such configuration at HiveConf. all hadoop command can be run from Hive CLI. e.g. hive> dfs -setrep -w file-path.... or $hive -e "dfs -setrep -w file-path"

Comment: Isn't the `dfs.replication.min` used ONLY during safe mode?

Comment: @Gevorg yes, it is also used during the safe mode as well once every file has minimum replication HDFS exists the safe mode.

Comment: @user2950086 you can set replication for a directory and create all managed and external tables inside that directory to achieve desired replication.